# Can Travis CI cache docker images?

Tags: caching, docker, travis-ci

Is it possible to add a setting to cache my docker image anywhere in the travis configuration ? Mine is a bigger docker image and it takes a while for it to download.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305492/cache-docker-images-on-travis-ci

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache docker images on Travis CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305492/cache-docker-images-on-travis-ci)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Caching Docker Images on Build #5358](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5358)
 for the answer(s). For Docker 1.12 available now on Travis, it is recommended to [manually cache the images](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5358#issuecomment-248915326). For the Docker 1.13, you could use its `--cache-from` when it is on Travis.

Save:

```
before_cache:
  # Save tagged docker images
  - >
    mkdir -p $HOME/docker && docker images -a --filter='dangling=false' --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} {{.ID}}'
    | xargs -n 2 -t sh -c 'test -e $HOME/docker/$1.tar.gz || docker save $0 | gzip -2 > $HOME/docker/$1.tar.gz'
```

Load:

```
before_install:
  # Load cached docker images
  - if [[ -d $HOME/docker ]]; then ls $HOME/docker/*.tar.gz | xargs -I {file} sh -c "zcat {file} | docker load"; fi
```

Also need to declare a cache folder:

```
cache:
  bundler: true
  directories:
    - $HOME/docker
```

Comment: Would you mind to add the code to your answer? Links may break at some point.

Comment: sorry, haven't seen your comment before; now a lot is different (and the links still work) so I will leave it as is

Answer (score 16):

Simplest solution today (October 2019) is to add the following to `.travis.yml`:

```
cache:
  directories:
  - docker_images

before_install:
- docker load -i docker_images/images.tar || true

before_cache:
- docker save -o docker_images/images.tar $(docker images -a -q)
```

Comment: This does indeed work, but it might be noteworthy that the mentioned steps all have a cost attached to them. In my particular case it actually took more time in total to store and load the travis cache itself and perform `docker store` and `docker load` than to just rebuild the images. So the above might only be useful if the cached layers are relatively small, but expensive to build, such as when compiling a relatively small binary with a slow compiler, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Docker images are not recommended to be cached regard to Travis document here
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#things-not-to-cache

Comment: The Travis document sounds outdated.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the following approach as discussed in this [article](https://medium.com/mobileforgood/coding-tips-patterns-for-continuous-integration-with-docker-on-travis-ci-9cedb8348a62).

```
services:
  - docker

before_script:
  - docker pull myorg/myimage || true
script:
  - docker build --pull --cache-from myorg/myimage --tag myorg/myimage .
  - docker run myorg/myimage

after_script:
  - docker images

before_deploy:
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: docker push myorg/myimage
  on:
    branch: master
```

Comment: that doesnt cache the images between builds

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

- Update the desired docker image name instead of `<IMAGE_NAME_HERE>` (3 places).
- You can also use the same configuration for multiple images, `docker save` can handle multiple images, just make sure to pull them before trying to save them.

```
services:
  - docker

cache:
  directories:
    - docker-cache

before_script:
  - |
    filename=docker-cache/saved_images.tar
    if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then docker load < "$filename"; fi
    mkdir -p docker-cache
    docker pull <IMAGE_NAME_HERE>
    docker save -o "$filename" <IMAGE_NAME_HERE>

script:
  - docker run <IMAGE_NAME_HERE>...
```